# Passing id in form_for action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form to update an attribute of a model - I don't want it to go to the standard update action I want it to go to a different action.

```
<% for car in @cars %>
 <%= form_for car, :url => { :action => "custom_action/#{car.id}" } do |f| -%>
```

This is giving the following error -

```
No route matches {:action=>"custom_action/1", :controller=>"cars"}
```

However if I visit the url - custom_action/1 - I don't get the routing error.

Any idea why I can't do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what Frederick Cheung said about GET vs POST vs PUT, I think your code might be wrong in general.

To do exactly what you want, try:

```
form_for car, :url => {:action => "custom_action", :id => car, :controller => "cars"} do |f|
```

I don't think this is a good idea, and will probably cause you pain. I suggest taking a look at the [Ruby on Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), to understand how to do this properly. (Routing is a topic where I always have to consult the manual.)

With correct routes your code should look something like this:

```
form_for car, custom_action_car_path(car) do |f|
```

Which will be easier to change in the future if/when you refactor your app.

Comment: Thanks very much - having a look at the routes now.

Comment: In your routes you'll want something like `resources :cars do; post :custom_action, :on => :member; end` Then you can use `custom_action_cars_path(car)` in your controllers and views.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the url by typing it into the url bar, you're making a `GET` request, whereas forms emit `POST` requests by default, and in this case would probably emit a `PUT` request (since you're acting on an existing record).

It sounds like your route is only routing `GET` requests. Given that you say your custom action does update the record, it sounds like you should update your routes to accept `PUT` requests instead.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense. I'm going to try and sort my routes out as per Ryan's answer.